# How to get all the <li> in <ul> tag in CodeBehind?

Tags: asp.net, html-lists

I can get the page `<ul>` in code behind like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl ul = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("newsList");
```

and I can also get the specified `<li>` like this:

```
 HtmlAnchor li = (HtmlAnchor)Page.FindControl("news_one");
```

But how can I get all the `<li>` in `<ul>` dynamic? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would  you can do it like this:

```
x = 5;
li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.Attributes.Add("class", "myItemClass");
li.InnerText = "Item " + x;

myList.Controls.Add(li);
```

wherein you can loop the value of x depending on how much you would like to output li

Comment: Thanks your your response,and it is usefull for me.